# Code works on iPhone simulator but not on the device

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm using the following code to switch between two different skins/themes in an ipad app.
The code works fine in the simulator but not on the device. Can anyone give any suggestions as to why this might be happening?

```
    if (skin == 1) {

            UIImage* skinSelector = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"];
            self.imgSkinSelector = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:skinSelector];
            self.imgSkinSelector.center = CGPointMake(88, 88);
            self.imgSkinSelector.alpha = 0;
            [self.landscape addSubview:self.imgSkinSelector];


    }

    else {

            UIImage* skinSelector2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button2.png"];
            self.imgSkinSelector = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:skinSelector2];
            self.imgSkinSelector.center = CGPointMake(74, 74);
            [self.landscape addSubview:self.imgSkinSelector];
    //      self.skinSelector.hidden = 1;


    }
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Have you tried to debug it? What line gives you unexpected result? You really provided not enough details...

Comment: Why are the center points different if you choose a different skin?

Comment: there's a point that when touched reveals skin2/theme2 and when touched again reveals skin1/theme1 etc... maybe it was because of the center points being off. I would have thought that the center points being off would also have had the same result in the simulator as on the device.

Answer (score 2):

I once faced a problem where Simulator was correctly picking the resources (images) but not the device (iPhone).

At least in my case it turned out to be the case of image names. Make sure the name of image is exactly as written in code (button.png / Button.png etc.)

Just a guess...

Answer (score 2):

may b some problem with your images it shows fine in simulator but not in device ...just 4 a try use another image in place of that .
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Firstly, don't alloc **imgSkinSelector** every time you want to change your theme. Alloc/init only once in your viewDidLoad/loadView function like below:

```
self.imgSkinSelector = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

Then in your function, where you are changing theme, use this code:

```
if (skin == 1) {

[self.imgSkinSelector setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"]];
self.imgSkinSelector.center = CGPointMake(88, 88);
self.imgSkinSelector.alpha = 0;
[self.landscape addSubview:self.imgSkinSelector];
```

}
else {

```
[self.imgSkinSelector setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button2.png"]];
self.imgSkinSelector.center = CGPointMake(74, 74);
[self.landscape addSubview:self.imgSkinSelector];
```

}

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I would also remove the call to `addSubView` in both `if` and `else`. You don't want to add same view multiple times.